# Why does the page move vs the cell when using the up, down, and side to side buttons?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Help please. When I have excel open and am attempting to move the cursor from cell to cell using the up,down, and side to side keys on my keyboard, the entire page moves and the cell stays static. How do I get the cell to move instead of the page?

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I get the cell to move instead of the page?

Press the scroll lock key <kbd>ScrLk</kbd> on your keyboard.
If your keyboard doesn't have a <kbd>ScrLk</kbd> key, or if you can't find it, you can right click on the words "Scroll Lock" (next to the word "Ready") on the bottom left of the Excel window. This will open a pane with settings that you can toggle on or off. Find "Scroll Lock" in this list and toggle it off.

> **What is Scroll Lock?**
>
> Usually, the arrow keys will move you one cell at a time in whatever
> direction you wish. However, when Scroll Lock is enabled, the
> worksheet is "scrolled" instead. The up and down arrow keys scroll one
> row up and down, and the right and left arrow keys scroll one column
> right and left. The active cell never changes.

Source [How to disable Scroll Lock in Excel](https://exceljet.net/how-to-disable-scroll-lock-in-excel)